# How to grab elements by data-attribute with JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to grab the data-attribute value of two `li` elements. However, this does not work, because I don't seem to reference the right object (`el`) to grab them. The `el` is the currentTarget that holds the event listener.

Right now I grab them like this:

```
const refinementData = el.dataset.identifier
```

I need this data-attribute value (`data-identifier`) for a if-condition and iteration.

In first iteration this works fine and grabs the `li` elements.

In 2nd iteration it does not work because `el` also references other dom-elements (like e.g. a `span`). It tries to find the data-attribute (`data-identifier`) on the `span` and returns `undefined` then.

I tried alternatives to `el` e.g. jQuery solutions like this:

```
const refinementData2 = $('.refinement-list[data-identifier]');
```

or normal JavaScript versions like these:

```
const refinementData2 = document.querySelector('.refinement-list');
```

This is the HTML / Twig file where I want to grab values from the two `li` items:

```
                <div class="refinement-options tag-options js-action-element">
                    <ul>
                        {% for refinement in concreteProduct.productOptions.refinements %}
                            {# create <li> with color of refinement key #}
                            {% if refinement.key != 'V00' %}<li class="refinement-list with-icon without-text svg-refinement {{refinement.key|lower}} {{refinement.key == pre_config_refinement ? 'active': ''}} option"
                            data-refinement="{{refinement.key}}" data-identifier="refinement"></li>{% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% for tag in concreteProduct.productOptions.tags %}
                            {# create <li> with tag icon #}
                            {% if tag.key != 'T00' %}<li class="refinement-list with-icon without-text svg-tag {{tag.key|lower}} {{tag.key == pre_config_tag ? 'active': ''}} option" data-tag="{{tag.key}}" data-identifier="tag"></li>{% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Just as a side note, a class name with `-list` at the end is not ideal for an `LI` tag because the list is actually the parent: `UL` (unordered list). The `LI` is a list item. It obviously does not change how it works but when working with other people, it can avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: yes, you are right. thx!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason why you cannot get the right object is because it is a list. You need to iterate.

And regarding the way you get this info with jQuery, one way is to use the `data` method. For `data-identifier`, you call `.data('identifier')`.

```
$('.refinement-list').each(function(){
  console.log( $(this).data('identifier') );
});
```

Comment: For best practice and better UX use `console` instead of  `alert`

Comment: You are missing `.`

Comment: Yes I'll change that thank you. The `alert` is only a placeholder anyway, the author of the question will do something meaningful with it. I was just using this example to show how to retrieve `data-` property values

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving `li` at first. This way, you can narrow it exactly to the el.

```
 $('li.refinement-list[data-identifier]')
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('li.refinement-list[data-identifier]').each(function(i, obj) {
  console.log(obj.innerHTML, $(obj).attr('data-identifier'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="refinement-options tag-options js-action-element">
  <ul>
    <li class="refinement-list with-icon without-text svg-refinement {{refinement.key|lower}} {{refinement.key == pre_config_refinement ? 'active': ''}} option" data-refinement="{{refinement.key}}" data-identifier="refinement">a</li>
    <li class="refinement-list with-icon without-text svg-tag {{tag.key|lower}} {{tag.key == pre_config_tag ? 'active': ''}} option" data-tag="{{tag.key}}" data-identifier="tag">b</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```